# Distortion of OFDM signal when using RRC filter

Tags: filter-design, ofdm, filtering, equalization, equalizer

I am trying to transmit OFDM signal in pass-band based on RRC filter, but what I noticed that the signal before the RRC filter is completely different compared with signal after the RRC filter (It means the signal is destroyed when using RRc filter).  I tried to follow the signal without using any channel, I noticed the issue starts when using the RRC filter. For example,  I used only the system as follows:

```
signal --> ifft --> upsampling --> RRC filter --> RRC filter --> downsampling --> fft --> received signal
```

What is expected is the `received signal` equals to `signal`, but I get very different results.

what I get is a different signal. Why ? should that be equal? I think I must be the same.
Finally , when I delete the filter, Everything is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code in my PC, you need just to delete the delay added before the filter. For example, you can use:

```
U_aft_fil = U_aft_fil(fil_delay+1:end);
```

Then when filtering it again at the receiving side, you delete it again :

```
U_r_fil = U_r_fil(fil_delay+1:end);
```

Good luck

Comment: Yes, I get BER = 0;  Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice answer, Zeyad. I'll just conclude what you explained to me in the comments under my answer: This works here, because your channel is really only the RRC, designed to have zeros in the right places. If your channel also incorporates actual frequency-selectivity in the band of interest, then that OFDM receiver needs to correct that, too. And, because a real-world channel has unknown, and non-integer-sample delay, you will need to have a working OFDM synchronization at work before you can decimate so that the Nyquist properties make the RRCs "invisible" to the OFDM system.

Answer (score 0):

> In the above code, x must equal y,

No, not at all.

1. your `x` is time domain, but your `y` is frequency domain.
2. You're filtering the signal. That changes it. Even if you compared `y` to the input of `ifft`, they cannot be the same.
3. You're adding delay in the upsampled version: twice the group delay of your RRC, and once your `fil_delay` zeros, but then you're just decimating the result down without compensating that delay.
4. Your decimation isn't a multiple of the delay, and therefore, it will lead to a fractional sample delay in the output. That's normal, and a real OFDM receiver has to deal with that, but your system is not a full OFDM receiver, it's just the FFT – hence, you'll never see the same input as output.

The fact that you have a delay in there that happens to be half the RRC length kind of suggests you might have been trying to compensate filter delay, but instead you're adding more delay.

Also, `upsample` just inserts zeros between each input sample, so I doubt this is actually the operation you're looking for.

---

smaller remarks, which don't affect functionality:

- Filtering with the same RRC twice is the same as filtering with the RC once. THe order doesn't matter, you can add your delay afterwards or before or between. (but I really think you're doing something wrong when adding the delay at all. You need to do the exact opposite)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109619/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-distortion-of-ofdm-signal-when-using-rrc-f).